# Why are there post edits with no editor names associated?

Tags: discussion

I always see posts that have no editor names under its edits, like in this screenshot (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146297/hidden-features-of-xcode?lq=1)):

[image]

I wonder what this means - who edited that post and why does it show like that?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts. check this for more info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Community wiki posts never display avatars. The stats "8 revs, 3 users 72% senseful" replace  the usual info. Click to see the full history with all editor names and avatars.

The idea is that responsibility for such posts is supposed to be shared.

Comment: I was talking about the "edits", not the asker area.

Comment: @ZinanXing The original author and the editor(s) of the post are lumped together for Community Wiki. That's all.